# Jquery create slide have increase speed each step

Tags: jquery, slide, smoothing

I'm building a slider which need smooth speed and the speed automatci increase each step. check the site for better understand , just click the next and back button: 
http://www.goldmansachs.com/what-we-do/index.html

So you will see when click the next button , the current slide will move right to left from slow to fast and very fast in next short time.

and the next slider which will replace the current slider is moving very fast then begin slower and stop at the left of page.

I'm only need one element in each slide , not many element in each slide as goldmansachs. Can you tell me which script , or any tutorial or any jquery plugin that can provide this effect?

I tried myself. I can build a script to make the speed change smooth and slow from start then begin faster and very fast! However The stop of slider can't be a fixed place! it mean it could be move a little of longer or shoter! So the next slider will stop in front or back of the left side page!

Thanks!